# How do you change a row label on a return value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

The code I've written for my return value is:

```
val = df["end"].value_counts()
```

and it currently returns:

```
A    24
B    20
C    90
```

I'd like to change the A and B labels to say Cars and Trucks.

**for example:** for the values of 24 and 20.

How can I do it?
thank you very much

Comment: If I understand correctly; A, B and C are the column names in your dataframe, df. Why can't you change them in the file itself before proceeding. Please provide more information if this is not your question

Answer (score 1):

You can change your line to:

```
val = df["end"].replace(to_replace = {'A':'Cars', 'B':'Trucks'}).value_counts()
```

This won't alter your existing df.

If you want your existing df changed, use the following to apply the .replace() to the entire df.

```
df = df.replace(to_replace = {'A':'Cars', 'B':'Trucks'})
val = df['end'].value_counts()
```